# What counts as a creature "in play"?

Tags: epic-spell-wars

There's a source that heals you for each creature in play. Obviously creatures already kept (both yours and your opponents) count.

However, do unresolved creatures in your own spell count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This came up in a game of my own yesterday, and seeing that there was no answer here, I asked [over at BoardGameGeek](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1533032/when-creature-actually-play).

According to Matt Hyra (the lead developer of the game) Creature cards in your spell are in play as long as they're revealed.

Therefore unresolved creature cards in the same spell **do** count towards the resolution of Baconus the Butcher's ability. Other players' face down creatures **do not** count.

Comment: Rereading Matt's answer on BGG, he actually says that they're not Creatures if they're "unrevealed", not "unresolved". This means that Baconus _does_ count. I'll edit the answer to correct this mistake.

Comment: @Samthere I think this probably counts as a "substantial content edit," as discussed over in [this meta post](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/1517/can-i-make-a-substantial-content-edit-to-an-answer-in-these-circumstances). The accepted solution in that post is to create a new answer to the question with the correct information. I'm not sure if that applies here, but I wanted to point it out.

Comment: @SocioMatt As I was writing the edits I realised it was not so much a mistake on winterblood's part as an unclear wording; I think the content is ultimately the same but I changed some phrasing to make it clear which part he was talking about at the end (adding the "same spell" part, to differentiate between other people's spells that haven't started resolving). I appreciate the pointer, though!